# Проблема с накопление запросов и их последующей массовой отправкой на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Доброго времени суток!

На сайте стоит setInterval 30сек. на отправку запроса на сервер (/check/user), что бы получить данные о пользователе и отправить накопленную статистику.

По логам на сервере видно, что иногда от именно от одного IP приходит подряд 100-300 запросов  на адрес проверки (/check/user)... в секунду по 20 штук.
проблема возникает именно с этим запросом, то есть совсем не похоже на dos.

Такое ощущение, что при определенных условиях, запросы как бы накапливаются, и потом все вместе, дружной группой летят на сервер.

Что это за поведение? И как бы его предотвратить?

Спасибо за вниманием.

```
setInterval(() => {
   $.post('/user/check'), function (user) {
      API.user.setToken(user);
   })
}, 60000)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем каждые 30 секунд отправлять запрос? Что обновляется? Так-то, вебсокет лучше использовать для этой задачи. И скиньте пару строчек ошибки лучше, а не обрезанный скриншот

Comment: Согласен что реализация сомнительная. И правильно бы использоваться сокеты. Но к сожалению на текущий момент нету ресурса для обновления стека технологий.

Comment: Добавил полный скриншот логов и и пример кода прикрепил

Comment: Это известная проблема, пользователь просто оставил вкладку открытой, но при этом пользовался браузером на других вкладках. Браузер ставит выполнение скриптов на паузу. В это время setInterval только считает сколько он пропустил итераций. И потом он их все выполнит, как только пользователь перейдет на вашу вкладку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да все так и есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `setInterval()` на `setTimeout()`. Это решит вашу проблему.

Можно отслеживать момент переключения вкладок событиями:

```
window.addEventListener ( "blur",  ()={ /* ушли с вкладки */ } )
window.addEventListener ( "focus", ()={ /* открыли вкладку */ } )
window.addEventListener ( "unload", ()={ /* закрыли вкладку */ } )
```

Comment: Выходит что когда таба становиться не активной, колбэк setTimeout  не будет выполнятся?

Comment: @AnthonyV, будет или не будет выполняться setTiemout - зависит от браузера, пользователя и окружения. Но, по крайней мере, новых итераций он точно создавать не будет.

Comment: @AnthonyV немного расширило ответ про события, вероятно, это вам поможет.